# Powershell: Storing variables in a directory to be called back inside a For command

Tags: powershell

I am relatively new to powershell coding, i am trying to create a script which auto runs a system key grab. However i am struggling with the naming system. I am using a directory of previous tests but cant seem to figure out a way to call it with my script. Im trying to have my $Num variable change and stay changed after my script is run.

```
gci -Recurse -Path E:\temp | Measure-Object.Count
for($Num.Count ; $Num -le 300; $Num++){

Write-Output Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
start-sleep -Seconds 05
Write-Output A
Write-Output Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo -RequiredVersion 3.5
start-sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output Y
start-sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output Y
start-sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output Y
Write-Output Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 | Out-File -FilePath E:\temp\kpf-Laptop$num.txt -NoClobber

Write-Output $Num

Exit


}
```

Comment: This has so many syntax errors and will never work. `Measure-Object` is a cmdlet, not a variable that has a `.Count` **property**. Your `for()` loop starts off with an undefined variable `$Num` from which you take a `.Count` property (which it doesn't have..). What is the use of installing a script X times over depending on the number of files you have in your E:\Temp folder?. Please, rethink what you intend to do and make that clear in your question.

Comment: So the point of needed to install the script multiple times is that the script will be used on multiple computers right now the number of computers which have autopilots are 124. This is the basic For command but i need to be able to save the variable once run. So every time a file is spat out it is $num+1.    for($Num = 125 ; $Num -le 300; $Num++){

Comment: Then that's another thing you didn't mention.. Your code is also not trying to connect with different computers. Take some time first and google for the workings of the cmdlets you think you will need like `Invoke-Command` and `Measure-Object`. Also you don't want to **Exit**.

Comment: Again i get the feeling you've misinterpreted me, the script is run on different computers to spit out the system key. This would be output as KPF-Laptop$Num where num is name of the laptop on my system. as said before it is currently at number 124. Do you have any ideas on how i can get that $num to cache outside the script either directories or childitems. and then have it be called back when the script is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to storing a variable after a powerscript has run. This script will save and change the $file_data even after the script is closed.

```
Get-Content D:\pscript\temp\Directory.txt
[int] $file_data = Get-Content D:\pscript\temp\Directory.txt

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

for ([int]$file_data -le 130; $file_data++ ){
Write-Output Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
start-sleep -Seconds 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
start-sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output A
Write-Output Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo -RequiredVersion 3.5
start-sleep -Seconds 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
start-sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output Y
start-sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output Y
start-sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output A
Write-Output Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 | Out-File -FilePath D:\pscript\AutoPilot\Laptop$file_data.csv -NoClobber


Set-Content D:\pscript\temp\Directory.txt $file_data


exit
}
```